# Plasmashell crashed and won't restart from terminal (AMD 6700XT)

Tags: kde, plasma

My Plasma crashed and I can't do anything about it. Everything froze, can't move the mouse either. If I am trying to restart Plasma from another terminal with kstart5 plasmashell it says qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qp.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb in" even though it was found

Any solution or should I go back to Ubuntu? This is utterly annoying. I am on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS and I have an AMD Radeon RX6700XT graphics card, using preinstalled Ubuntu drivers. I am fairly sure it is a plasmashell issue.

Comment: makes `plasmashell --replace` or `plasmashell5 --replace` the same? and is this the full output?

Comment: I get the same error when I type plasmashell --replace. It's not the full error output, no. How can I copy and paste it from terminal? It doesn't allow to use my mouse in terminal 2

Comment: Did you updated your system, before Plasma did crashes?

Comment: It's a Kubuntu 22.04 LTS and yes I did update my system. I am not sure if it's due to the recent updates or from my hardware/drivers. How could I find out what is causing the freezing of my OS?